# JavaScript - Convert JSON Array into HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JSON Array of messages that I need to convert into html elements to use for displaying in my web page. The JSON that I'm receiving looks like this:

```
    {
    "data": [
        {
            "fieldData": {
                "Message": "Message 1",
                "Timestamp": "04/14/2023 11:39:13"
            }
        },
        {
            "fieldData": {
                "Message": "Message 2",
                "Timestamp": "04/13/2023 10:02:18"
            }
        },
        {
            "fieldData": {
                "Message": "Message 3",
                "Timestamp": "08/19/2021 19:51:21"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to extract each 'Message' and 'Timestamp' Value from the Array and place them in tags like the following for the first array:

```
<p class="from-them">Message 1</p>
<time class="timestamp-to">04/14/2023 11:39:13</time>
```

So using the sample JSON above the end result would be:

```
<p class="from-them">Message 1</p>
<time class="timestamp-to">04/14/2023 11:39:13</time>
<p class="from-them">Message 2</p>
<time class="timestamp-to">04/13/2023 10:02:18</time>
<p class="from-them">Message 3</p>
<time class="timestamp-to">08/19/2021 19:51:21</time>
```

It's my first time trying to write a JavaScript function to convert an array into individual html elements and not sure where to start here.

Comment: You have asked almost 150 questions tagged JavaScript over 10 years and you still don't know where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. convert your JSON in a normal Object that JS can use either by using the `map()` function or by simply parsing the JSON with `JSON.parse()`
2. then use a for-loop that loops through every object within the array
3. Use `createElements` to actually create that element:

```js
let json_data = `{
  "data": [
    {
      "fieldData": {
        "Message": "Message 1",
        "Timestamp": "04/14/2023 11:39:13"
      }
    },
    {
      "fieldData": {
        "Message": "Message 2",
        "Timestamp": "04/13/2023 10:02:18"
      }
    },
    {
      "fieldData": {
        "Message": "Message 3",
        "Timestamp": "08/19/2021 19:51:21"
      }
    }
  ]
}`;

// parse JSON
let data = JSON.parse(json_data);


// loop to create the elements
for (let messageIndex = 0; messageIndex < data.data.length; messageIndex++) {
  let message = data.data[messageIndex].fieldData.Message;
  let timestamp = data.data[messageIndex].fieldData.Timestamp;
  
  // create Message
  let messageElement = document.createElement('p');
  messageElement.classList.add('from-them');
  messageElement.textContent = message;
  document.body.appendChild(messageElement);
  
  // create Timestamp
  let timestampElement = document.createElement('time');
  timestampElement.classList.add('timestamp-to');
  timestampElement.textContent = timestamp;
  document.body.appendChild(timestampElement);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To make a html element, you need to do something like:

```
var pElement = document.createElement('p'); //use different parameter to make different elements
pElement.className = 'className';
pElement.textContent = 'textContent';
// and essentially you put it in the DOM
document.body.appendChild(pElement);
```

Now, you just need to make a for loop (for "data") and within each iteration make the p element and time element, and append them to the DOM.